# Locating elements in section with selenium

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to enter text into a field (the subject field in the image) in a section using Selenium .
I've tried locating by Xpath , ID and a few others but it looks like maybe I need to switch context to the section.   I've tried the following, errors are in comments after lines.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
opts = Options()
browser = Firefox(options=opts)
browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/feed/')

sign_in = '/html/body/div[1]/main/p/a'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(sign_in).click()
email = '//*[@id="username"]'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(email).send_keys(my_email)

pword = '//*[@id="password"]'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(pword).send_keys(my_pword)

signin = '/html/body/div/main/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[3]/button'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(signin).click()

search = '/html/body/div[8]/header/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/input'
name = 'John McCain'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(search).send_keys(name+"\n")#click()

#click on first result
first_result = '/html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/main/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span/div/span[1]/span/a/span/span[1]'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(first_result).click()

#hit message button
msg_btn = '/html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/main/div/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/a'

browser.find_element_by_xpath(msg_btn).click()
sleep(10)


  ## find subject box in section 
section_class = '/html/body/div[3]/section'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(section_class)   # no such element
browser.switch_to().frame('/html/body/div[3]/section') # no such frame

subject = '//*[@id="compose-form-subject-ember156"]'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(subject).click()  # no such element
compose_class = 'compose-form__subject-field'
browser.find_element_by_class_name(compose_class)  # no such class
id = 'compose-form-subject-ember156'
browser.find_element_by_id(id) # no such element
css_selector= 'compose-form-subject-ember156'
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector) # no such element
    
wind = '//*[@id="artdeco-hoverable-outlet__message-overlay"]
browser.find_element_by_xpath(wind) #no such element
```

A figure showing the developer info for the text box in question is attached.
How do I locate the text box and send keys to it? I'm new to selenium but have gotten thru login and basic navigation to this point.

I've put the page source (as seen by the Selenium browser object at this point)  [here](https://gist.github.com/jeremy-rutman/aa7b4611e9a2525323da3490de3b81e2).

The page source (as seen when I click in the browser window and hit 'copy page source') is [here](https://gist.github.com/jeremy-rutman/1ce5d35b644e972f56ca2bf479a21fce) .
[image: dev tools for page in question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the window in focus being the one I wanted it seems like the browser object saw things differently . Using

```
window_after = browser.window_handles[1]
browser.switch_to_window(window_after)
```

allowed me to find the element using an Xpath.